# how to get particular key value from an object array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below :

```
Array ( [3] => 
   stdClass Object ( 
         [Course_ID] => php01 
         [Course_Type] => E 
         [Course_Name] => PHP 
         [Service] => 3L 
         [Valid_Start_Date] => 2015-11-05 
         [Valid_End_Date] => 2016-01-31 
         [Duration] => 3 
         [Re_cert_Years] => 0 
         [LMS_Course_ID] => 123 
         [id] => 3
     ) 
        [21] => 
    stdClass Object ( 
        [Course_ID] => php01 
        [Course_Type] => E 
        [Course_Name] => PHP 
        [Service] => 3L 
        [Valid_Start_Date] => 2015-11-05 
        [Valid_End_Date] => 2016-01-31 
        [Duration] => 3 
        [Re_cert_Years] => 0 
        [LMS_Course_ID] => 123 
        [id] => 21 
     ) 
  )
```

i want to get the value of Course_ID.

How to get the value from this array ?

Comment: What you have tried for it???

Comment: Try `$ret[3]->Course_ID`

Comment: my resulted array is stored in $ret variable. so i tried $ret['Course_ID']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accessing Object key in PHP use `->` operator Have you tried like following:

```
foreach($ret as $index=>$obj){
    echo $obj->Course_ID;
}
```

It will print 2 courseID because your array of object contains 2 object. if you want to print any particular index then use this:

```
echo $ret[3]->Course_ID;
echo $ret[21]->Course_ID; //where 3 or 21 is index of array
```

Comment: if i use this means the Course_ID will printed two times. how to solve